# How to generate unique link to video everytime user play it in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

I'm working on video web app, I faced with an issue. When visitor/user play video on web, it should have below conditions:

1. Generate unique security link and hide the direct link to the mp4 file. User with skill can't trace the direct link.
2. The link should be expired in xx time.
3. User/visitor can't download the video (by using browser save (Ctr + S) feature).

How do I do this in nodejs? I will host the mp4 files on AWS S3.

Thank you

Comment: For 1 and 2, you have to proxy the actual URL so that all that it is ever sent to the client is the generated url and the browser can actually play that generated URL through your proxy.   And, your proxy would know when to expire the generated rul. That means your proxy also has to support any requests that a video player might use such as requesting byte ranges.  I don't think #3 is possible.  If the browser can play it, a determined hacker can save it or record it.  You could, of course, block a keystroke like Ctrl+S in your web page if that's all you're trying to stop.

Comment: Thank you for your suggession, I'm new to nodejs and haven't use proxy before. Can you send me some examples about using proxy in similar case? Thank you

Comment: I posted an answer that has links to a few examples.

Answer (score 1):

For 1 and 2, you have to proxy the actual URL so that all that it is ever sent to the client is the generated url and the browser can actually play that generated URL through your proxy. And, your proxy would know when to expire the generated url.

That means your proxy also has to support any requests that a video player might use such as requesting byte ranges. I don't think #3 is possible. If the browser can play it, a determined hacker can save it or record it. You could, of course, block a keystroke like Ctrl+S in your web page if that's all you're trying to stop.

For more info on implementing a simple proxy, see [this example](https://github.com/ScottyFillups/node-video-proxy) and plenty of other discussion of that topic [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=npm%20video%20proxy).

For timing out the URL, you will either have to incorporatean expiration time into your uniquely generated URL so you can easily check it when processing or when you go to your database to look up what the real URL is that corresponds to your temporary one, you can also get back the expiration time from the database to decide if it is still valid or not.  Then, with a  chron job, you could also clean out expired URLs from the database so they don't accumulate forever.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. So I have to create new proxy nodejs app? I can't integrate it to current nodejs app, right? In this proxy server, I will have a GET method, received video URL then it will return to me encrypted video URL, am I understant it correctly?

Comment: @kien - No, you don't have to create a new app.  You can integrate it right into your current app.  This [example](https://github.com/ScottyFillups/node-video-proxy/blob/master/api.js) shows just a simple request handler doing proxying from another server.

Comment: I tried to integrate proxy, it works but the video load very slow. It plays only 2 seconds and keep loading. I think I will use direct link, but I stuck in generating unique link. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @kien - If it stops after playing just a little bit, then that's usually a sign that you aren't passing the headers from the request through appropriately (specifically the [range header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range).  If you add the current version of your code to the end of your question, people can take a look at what you have so far.

Comment: @kien - FYI, proxying will always be slower than direct linking, but direct linking will never be secret and a determined client can get the direct link and save it and there's nothing you can do about that if you ever let the client have the direct link.  So, you have to choose what you want.